# Monaco Editor & Typescript: How to add global types?

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

How can I instruct the Monaco editor that a set of types is global? Here's what I've tried. With the setup below, I can successfully write `import type { Foo } from "my-lib";` into the Monaco editor. However, I want to allow the types in my-lib to be global so that the script being edited within Monaco does not have to explicitly import anything.

```
// setup compiler options
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2016,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    moduleResolution: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
    module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
    noEmit: true,
    typeRoots: ["node_modules/@types"],
    types: ["my-lib"] // <=== NOTE THIS
});

// define my-lib
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
    "export interface Foo { foo: number; }",
    "file:///node_modules/@types/my-lib/index.d.ts"
);

// create model
const model = monaco.editor.createModel(
    "const o: Foo = { foo: 23 };", // <=== this code will have an error in the Monaco editor
    "typescript",
    monaco.Uri.parse(`file:///main.ts`)
);

// create the editor
const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), { model });
```

[Monaco Editor Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.44.0#XQAAAALhAwAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw47HtRXxYGa_d-PvlZy4aByEOdnyi6BLk9FAouVJusOUm4jKSUtfo8mCuI0f2FX6Z_JvamZWz3LDrDrk0VllUmIhSxGJvTDCvvN7mxcowk1_LOZlxX9bhYdsbfvC2U-IYVhYrRP90olXY1qXmVSUuOA1bPFNJjyjfKSvK8rhYGWjeK6NUHVWtLx7rdo6KJ6m6w8ITSXxuIGTB6b-a54LOxov_h3k0vDAEfwCReWBOAVn2V-BOvp2dN5FTx7Rm6eFJF88UKYqTq0f92zHSRJzInbzId7SKYl9eUXO1bNP6T7bOxmnlqlqNrcZCftxtrRksqQFFIOqE4mDROja7GH3ifjTIR3YrAoKPgrfQWLuZRXh4lxZAoxhpXZ4jDbHW_kl-3t5aQfiyjITkR7lfcW-TIRBylPKGeFgQmc38oRVHMxUnaf83M01kSJV2rTwKHB1U5CdPBzRMCHEP_n6XEfdZNI_dHjXLtTOzbcQCQWe3_WK7Fs0BmPOBycKm7lZ8QO85HCllAHAQu26zJ3r_sk90Ydpbi8X1N9EHMeWtyUZDiedPpzsdY67_ymU7aCUx-Ffb_7gfhSJGFzMyGcEBzEJHW9CPPjHw7X5xE2kPEtJvlhHr_9Yiq5I)

Comment: What helps is to remove the `export` keyword from the interface definition. No idea why, though, but I guess exports make no sense in the editor, since it cannot export anything, only import them or declare them locally.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out a few hours after my post. If you would like to make an answer, I will mark this issue as solved. @MikeLischke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find an explanation why, but removing the `export` keyword from the source text makes Monaco accepting code which uses this interface.

Answer (score 1):

To declare global types in Typescript, you should use

```
declare global { interface Foo { foo: number; } }; export {}
```

or

```
interface Foo { foo: number; }
```

or if you do as you do now you may

```
import { Foo } from "my-lib";
```

in code